# PredictionIO - one engine and multiple algorithms

Tags: algorithm, predictionio

I am stuck with one engine and multiple algorithms and need help further.

I have one engine and 2 algorithms, let's call AL1 and AL2. 
In src/main/scala having 2 algorithm scala files, name AL1Algorithm.scala and AL2Algorithm.scala each algorithm have its own param and model  (AL1AlgorithmParams and AL1Model for AL1 and AL2AlgorithmParams and AL2Model for AL2).
Therefore there are 2 train functions and 2 predict functions.

I can train 2 algorithms by calling pio train.
When I call send_query to test, the program always return the result of the algorithm I put on the top of engine.json file

For instance, if I put AL1Algorithm on top, send_query will run AL1Algorithm

```
"algorithms": [
    {
      "name": "AL1Algorithm",
      "params": {
        "n": 100
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "AL2Algorithm",
      "params": {
        "n": 100
      }
    }
```

if I put AL2Algorithm on top, send_query will run AL2Algorithm'

```
"algorithms": [
    {
      "name": "AL2Algorithm",
      "params": {
        "n": 100
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "AL1Algorithm",
      "params": {
        "n": 100
      }
    }
```

My question is, can I call 2 algorithms for one send_query, how to distinguish which algorithm should be called in send_query instead of engine.json.
There is something weird here, I think there are problems with my configuration.
Will Serving.scala produce results of 2 algorithms at the same time. Can I split the results of each algorithm in serving.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You also need to modify the serve() function In Serving.scala. the serve() function has 2 arguments.  see below

```
def serve(query: Query,
   predictedResults: Seq[PredictedResult]): PredictedResult
```

The query is sent to both algorithms, and the `PredictedResult` returned by both algorithms are passed to `serve()` function as `Seq[PredictedResult]`. The `Seq[]` order is the same as the order of algorithm defined in `engine.json`. You need to modify this to make use of all `PredictedResult` output by algorithm. Some of the template examples by default only take the 1st result (`predictedResults.head`)

Please also see "Step 4. Modify Serving to combine multiple algorithms' outputs" in [this doc](https://docs.prediction.io/templates/similarproduct/multi-events-multi-algos/) as example.

Comment: Dear Kenneth, 
Thank you very much for your reply. I can get all of the result of 2 algorithms now by  override def serve(query: Query, predictedResults: Seq[PredictedResult]): PredictedResult = {
val standard: Seq[Array[ItemScore]] = predictedResults.map(_.itemScores) new PredictedResult(standard.flatten.toArray) }

Can you help me the way to split them, I have one parameter in query named "eventType", if eventType == "AL1" then I need the result of the first algorithm, if eventType == "AL2", outcome of algorithm 2 should return, and so on, if eventType == "ALn", then I need algorithm n.

Comment: One way to do it is to define PredictedResult as

Comment: (sorry, hit enter by mistake in previous comment) One way to do it is to add a field in your PredictedResult to indicate the result is coming from which algorithm. e.g. `case class PredictedResult(algoId: String,  itemScores: Array[ItemScore]) extends Serializable`, then in serving you can tell the PredictedResult is from which algorithm.